# zolertia z1 connection with tunslip for webserver

Tags: sensors, contiki

I want to install a webserver on my zolertia z1 sensor. I followed step here : [http://wismote.org/doku.php?id=development:sample_code](http://wismote.org/doku.php?id=development%3asample_code)

When i run tunslip program like this :

"sudo ./tunslip  -B 115200 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 "

Results are :

```
slip started on ``/dev/ttyUSB0''
opened device ``/dev/tun0''
ifconfig tun0 inet `hostname` up
route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev tun0
ifconfig tun0

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:127.0.1.1  P-t-P:127.0.1.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

The route on tun0 is opened but he doesn't detect my sensor connected with serial line. There no "route add -net 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev tun0" at end and i don't know why. I don't know if i must change the flag for a TAP or TUN device ?!

if i try to login on my sensor with "make login". it works fine. the program is 
correctly installed on this.

I tried this on a virtual image with contiki and on Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS x86_64. I have the same result on both OS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've to change your BaudRate which it's used to be arround 38.400 bauds on motes z1 Zolertia.

```
sudo ./tunslip -B 38400 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
```